# CREATE TYPE "XYZ" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(104) in postgresql

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I have converted the types from oracle to postgres using the

> ORa2pg

tool

```
CREATE  TYPE "XYZ" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(104)
```

The same is working fine in oracle . but the ora2pg converts the same as it is in postgres
with the warning as 
-- Unsupported, please edit to match PostgreSQL syntax

```
CREATE  TYPE "XYZ" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR(104)
```

Not Working in the postgres

I have tried the other queries as

```
create type XYZ as (xyz varchar[])
```

But the same is not usefull as it is not giving the desired result The Type does not match

Function is receiving the type Table of varchar but the

```
create type XYZ as (xyz varchar[])
```

is of composite type in postgres

Is there any way to have a type which is same as the above .. Pls Help

Comment: PostgreSQL does not support `TABLE OF [sometype]` parameters. You have to use refcursors instead.

Comment: @Craig Ringer I don't have much idea of refcursors , Could we do it without refcursors using create type XYZ as TABLE OF VARCCHAR(104)

Comment: No you can't - see my previous comment.

Comment: If you only have that for a table function, you don't really need that. You can simply declare the function as `returns setof varchar`. No "type" object required.